# special character "[" inside $_REQUEST

Tags: php, input, request, character

I'm trying to do a `$_REQUEST` with this "[" character inside.

Example:

```
input type="text" name="i18n[1][name]" value=""
```

Send to:

```
$_REQUEST["i18n[1][name]"]
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: When you tried it what did it do?

Comment: Try `$_REQUEST['i18n'][1]['name']`.

Comment: it do nothing... thats the problem..

Comment: Did you try what @brevis  suggests?

Comment: @brevis i try that and nothing..

Comment: i also try this: $_REQUEST["['i18n'][1]['name']"]

Comment: Show the rest of your form. Use var_dump or print_r. It should be self-evident

Comment: @brevis was right. it work like this: $_REQUEST['i18n'][1]['name']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_REQUEST['i18n'][1]['name']`

Thanks @brevis

Answer (score 0):

To see what the client is sending to the server, add

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

as the first line of the PHP code.

Use the results to code your script.